# Как сделать условие внутри массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив данных, которые потом циклом добавляет в базу, но быват что нет некоторых данных соответственно эту часть массива исключать.

```
if ($_GET['addvid'] == "leadadd") {

        $json_output = array();

        if (isset($_POST['name_lead']))     {$name = checkrequest(iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $_POST['name_lead']));}
        if (isset($_POST['phone_lead']))    {$phone = $_POST['phone_lead'];}
        if (isset($_POST['email_lead']))    {$email = checkrequest($_POST['email_lead']);}
        if (isset($_POST['channel_lead']))  {$source = checkrequest($_POST['channel_lead']);}
        if (isset($_POST['status_lead']))   {$status = checkrequest($_POST['status_lead']);}
        if (isset($_POST['address_lead']))  {$address_lead = checkrequest(iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $_POST['address_lead']));}
        if (isset($_POST['comment_lead']))  {$comment_lead = checkrequest(iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $_POST['comment_lead']));}
        if (isset($_POST['group_lead']))    {$id_group = checkrequest($_POST['group_lead']);}


        if (isset($_POST['name_lead']) or isset($_POST['phone']) or isset($_POST['email_lead'])) { /* то можно занести информацию */

            $id_c = $myrow_cabinet['id'];
            $id_staff = $userdata['id_staff'];

                $result_status = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM status WHERE id = '".$status."' and id_cabinet = '$id_c'");
                $myrow_status = mysql_fetch_array($result_status);

            $dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
            $add_vid = "hand";
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO lids (id_cabinet,id_staff,name,tel,id_type,email,source,comment,address,status,status_view,add_vid,datetime) VALUES ('$id_c','$id_staff','$name','$phone','$id_group','$email','$source','$comment_lead','$address_lead','$myrow_status[id]','1','$add_vid','$dates')");
            $id_new_lead = mysql_insert_id();

                if ($result == 'true') {                        
                    $json_output = array('succes'=>1, 'url_new_lead'=>'/'.$id_c.'/leads/details-'.$id_new_lead.'', 'msg'=>'<div class="lead-add-success"><div class="ucrmicon success-img">Q</div></div>'); 

                    // Добавление названий форм
                    $lead_add  = array(
                        array("vid_change" => "add", "coment_change" => "Добавлен клиент", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => ""),
                        array("vid_change" => "name", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$name"),
                        array("vid_change" => "phone", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$phone"),
                        array("vid_change" => "email", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$email"),
                        array("vid_change" => "address", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$address_lead"),
                        array("vid_change" => "comment", "coment_change" => "$comment_lead", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => ""),
                        array("vid_change" => "status", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$myrow_status[id]"),
                        array("vid_change" => "group", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$id_group")

                    );

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($lead_add); $i++) {
                       $item = $lead_add[$i];

                            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
                            $vid_change =  $lead_add[$i]['vid_change'];
                            $coment_change = $lead_add[$i]['coment_change'];
                            $change_old = $lead_add[$i]['change_old'];
                            $change_new = $lead_add[$i]['change_new'];
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO change_history (id_lid,datetime,vid_change,coment_change,change_old,change_new,id_staff,id_cabinet) VALUES ('$id_new_lead','$date','$vid_change','$coment_change','$change_old','$change_new','$id_staff','$id_c')");

                    }


                }
                else {                      
                    $json_output = array("succes"=>0, "msg"=>"<div class='lead-add-error'><div class='ucrmicon error-img'>N</div>Что-то не работает, сообщите в тех.поддержку!</div>");
                }

        }

        else {$json_output = array("succes"=>0, "msg"=>"<div class='lead-add-error'><div class='ucrmicon error-img'>N</div>Вы не заполнили обязательные поля!</div>");}

        echo json_encode($json_output); 
        exit;
}
```

Т.е. например не был указан в форме емайл, значит `array("vid_change" => "email", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$email"),` не участвует в формировании массива...

**Как такое сделать?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемента с `"vid_change"=> "address"` существовать не будет, т.к. не указана переменная $address.

```
<?php
$add = "test";
$name = "test";
$phone = "test";
$email = "test";
$comment = "test";
$status = "test";
$group = "test";

$lead_add  = array(
  array("vid_change" => "add", "coment_change" => "Добавлен клиент", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => ""),
  array("vid_change" => "name", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$name"),
  array("vid_change" => "phone", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$phone"),
  array("vid_change" => "email", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$email"),
  array("vid_change" => "address", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$address_lead"),
  array("vid_change" => "comment", "coment_change" => "$comment_lead", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => ""),
  array("vid_change" => "status", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$myrow_status[id]"),
  array("vid_change" => "group", "coment_change" => "", "change_old" => "", "change_new" => "$id_group")
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($lead_add); $i++) {
    $item = $lead_add[$i];

    if(!isset($$item["vid_change"])) {
        unset($lead_add[$i]);
    }
}

sort($lead_add);

print_r($lead_add);
?>
```

Comment: не работает... все равно добавляет...

Comment: у вас переменная не существует или там просто значения нету? если существует переменная, но без значения, измените `!isset($$item["vid_change"])` на `mb_strlen($$item["vid_change"], "UTF-8") == 0`

Comment: у меня переменная может быть как числом так и текстом

Comment: добавил полный код как у меня это было... что сделать чтобы не добавлялись те переменные которые не пришли или пришли но пустые... я измучался...

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev так вам надо что бы весь масив значений не записывался если нет какой либо переменной в нём?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev http://notepad.cc/hujipu8 вот, попробуйте

Comment: @naumov нет, тут идет формирование истории, смысл в том чтобы если например я в форме не указал адрес, тогда именно эта часть массива не срабатывает, а весь остальной массив будет добавляться.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev вы проверили мой код?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev тут всё просто достаточно `if` ввести в цикл и `continue` если нет то повторить со следуещем элементом

Comment: @ikerya проверил, но добавляет как-то странно, указываю все параметры но в истории показывает только телефон. имя, статус, и емайл остальное даже не пишет в базу не понятно почему...

Comment: @Naumov а можете показать на примере как, просто я хоть убей не пойму как в цикле это сделать!

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev ах, ну да, у вас просто переменные не так названы, попробуйте вот так: http://notepad.cc/hujipu8, надеюсь, ничего не упустил

Comment: @ikerya заработало вроде бы... спасибо за помощь

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev не за что :) если Вам подошло решение, можете ответить ответ, как правильный